# How to create an Increment Numeric String Value inside model and read the value inside Firebase Database using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For eg. what i want my Firebase data to be is structured like this
...
...
...
...

```js
"Food" 
        -> uid 
              -> 1 - name& value
                 2 - name& value
                 3  - name& value 
                 
        -> uid 
              -> 1 - name& value 
                 2 - name& value
                 3 - name& value
```

I just want to retrieve data from the FirebaseDatabase without inputting any data thru the app.

How do i create that Increment Numeric String value "1++" inside my model class without compromising the string

and read it using the recycler adapter as a string value of "x"

or is there another way to code this coz i am still new at this

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with the ViewHolder Function

```js
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ingredients, IngredientsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ingredients, IngredientsViewHolder>(
                Ingredients.class,
                R.layout.list_single_ingredients,
                IngredientsViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(IngredientsViewHolder viewHolder, Ingredients model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setX(model.getX());

            }
        };
        Ingredients_list.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


    }


    //ViewHolder
    public static class IngredientsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View m2View;

        public IngredientsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            m2View = itemView;
        }

        public void setX(String x) {
            TextView IngredientsView = (TextView) m2View.findViewById(R.id.txt_ingredients);
            IngredientsView.setText(x);

        }

    }


}
```

My Model class

```js
package Model;

/**
 * Created by Keiren on 1/4/2018.
 */

public class Ingredients {
    public String x;



    public Ingredients() {

    }
    public Ingredients(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }


    public String getX() {return x;}

    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you first need to convert your String into an int, increase the value and then convert the int back to a String like this:

```
String one = "1";
int two = Integer.valueOf(one);
two++;
String increasedValue = String.valueOf(two);
System.out.println(increasedValue);
```

The output will be: 2

Comment: the two++; will have a unexpected token

Comment: I tested the code above and works. Try to change this line `two++;` with: `two = two + 1;`

Comment: `unknown class` for what?

Answer (score 0):

I found the Answer to my own solution,
Change the it from

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Food").child(user_id);
to

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Food").child(user_id);

```js
"Food" 
        -> uid 
              -> 1 
                  -> x - name& value
                 2 
                  -> x- name& value
                 3  
                  -> x- name& value 
                 
        -> uid 
              -> 1 
                -> x - name& value 
                 2 
                 -> x - name& value 
                 3 
                 -> x - name& value
```